# JQuery - How to implement event listener for dynamically added droppable table rows?

Tags: jquery, droppable

I got an editable table where you can add rows dynamically with a button, but I cant drop my draggable stuff into the new rows even if they have the droppable-Selektor. I tried to fix it with delegate and `droppable()` for the new rows but failed. Any tips or ideas?

`Here is my Code:`http://jsfiddle.net/gM3bF/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `.droppable(options)` to your new row.

In order to make it work, I added a class to you new row :

```
var newtr = $('<tr />', { class: 'sortable-row ui-droppable newRow' });
```

And now add the droppable to this newRow (and finally remove this new useless class) :

```
$(".newRow") .droppable( {
        revert: true,
        drop: function (event, ui) {

            var id = ui.draggable.prop('id');
            if (id == "blurk") { var content = blurkContent(); };
            var title = $(event.target).closest('tr').children()[2];
            $(title).html(unescape(content[0]));
            var description = $(event.target).closest('tr').children()[3];
            $(description).html(unescape(content[1]));
            var link = $(event.target).closest('tr').children()[4];
            $(link).html(content[2]);
            var thumbnail = $(event.target).closest('tr').children()[5];
            $(thumbnail).html(content[3]);

        }
} )
$(".newRow").removeClass("newRow");
```

Of course you can simplify param you add creating a new var for this.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zhULn/)**

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you soo much! It worked! Just adding ".new row" and copying that droppable function from below. Now my script length has doubled but that's ok as long as it works ;)

Comment: Glad it help. You can define a new function containing the function in the "drop" parameter, this new function could now be called when initializing droppable and when adding a new droppable row. it's up to you. See the edited FIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/zhULn/1/

Comment: Oh yes thank you! I learned soo much from you and getting more and more comfortable with javascript/jquery. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
$(document).on(eventName, selector, function);
```

usage:

```
$(document).on('click', 'input.addButton', function(){ alert('clicked'); });

$(document).on('dblclick', '#editableTable td', function(){ alert('td clicked'); });

$(document).on('click', '#editableTable input.deleteButton', function(){ alert('delete clicked'); });
```

these you can declare **once** within the document ready event handler.

however,

if you're having dynamically added draggable elements, be sure to call `.draggable({})` **after** they were added to the DOM.

hope that helps.